# pthreads not work on fuelphp task

Tags: php, multithreading, fuelphp

I want to use task by multi thread.
I wrote following test batch(task) code.

fuel/app/tasks/test.php

```
<?php
namespace Fuel\Tasks;

class Test
{
    public static function run()
    {
        // worked
        \Foo_Bar::insert(10);

        $bar = new \Foo_Bar();

        // worked
        $bar->run();

        // not worked!!（Error: Class 'DB' not found）
        $bar->start();
        $bar->join();
    }
}
```

fuel/app/classes/foo/bar.php

```
<?php
class Foo_Bar extends Thread
{
    public static function insert($i)
    {
        DB::insert('test')->set(array(
            'i' => $i,
        ))->execute();
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->insert(20);
    }
}
```

Only in thread, DB class not found.
Why not work?
Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Please fix the spelling of "problem" in your title. Read and understand the ensuing error message. Further, I'd add "PHP" as a tag. That said, is the problem related to threading at all or does it also come up if you directly call the function? I guess you only need to add the necessary `require` statements or setup the autoloader properly.

Comment: I corrected spelling and added PHP tag. Thank you.
I'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code if your error is DB Class not working on your thread. Please add '\' before the class name. Example

```
\DB::insert
```